# Recharts/Chart js - Can I create radial stacked bar chart?

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, charts, chart.js, recharts

I'm evauating which library I should use for my project. For now my best options are Recharts and Chart js but i have one important type of chart that i would like to create.

So i am wondering if i can create chart like this in recharts or chart js + react-chart-js2 ? [image]
Basicly bar chart represented on a radar. Only similar solution I found is available in d3 as radial stacked bar chart. Even if it's not available out of the box maybe you could put me on the right track what i should seek to create chart like this in those libraries ?

I have looked trough documentation of multiple chart libraries but none meet my expectations. I need to create bars on area chart with 0 point placed in the middle of radar not in the center.

I've been trying to fiddle with area chart and I guess that have been my best shot for now yet it's still not meeting expectations.